# Chess Knight Distance

Tags: chessboard, knight-tours

On an $a×a$ chess-board knight takes $n$ jumps from the bottom left to the bottom right and $m$ jumps from the bottom left to the upper right.

For $a=7$ are 4 steps necessary.

Is $a=7$ the only number such that $n=m=4$?

Comment: If is obvious that for $a=7$ the minimum value of both $m$ and $n$ is 4. It is also obvious that for $a>9$ we will need $n>4$ and for $a>7$ we will need $m>4$. But some checking is needed for smaller values. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the bottom left corner be $(1,1)$, so the upper right corner is $(a,a)$.

Each move of the knight changes the parity of exactly one coordinate.
Hence, we always need an even number of moves to reach $(k,k)$, but when $k$ is even we need an odd number of moves to reach $(k,1)$.

It follows that when $a$ is even it is never possible to have $m=n$.

---

When $a$ is odd, the total movement to reach $(a,1)$ is $(a-1,0)$.
It can be reached with a combination of optimal moves $(4,0) = (2,1) + (2,-1)$, followed possibly by a move $(2,0) = (1,2)+(1,-2)$.

Hence, for $a - 1 = 4m$ we require $2m$ moves and for $a - 1 = 4m + 2$ we require $2m + 2$ moves.
We can combine these as $n = 2\left\lceil (a-1)/4\right\rceil$ moves.

---

On the other hand, each knight move increases the sum of coordinates by at most $3$, so we would require that $m$ be *at least*

$$\left\lceil \frac{2(a-1)}3\right\rceil.$$

It's easy to see hence that for $a$ large enough (say, $a\geqslant 13$) we have $m>n$.

---

You can verify the cases of odd $a<13$ with $2\left\lceil (a-1)/4\right\rceil \geqslant \left\lceil 2(a-1)/3\right\rceil$ by hand (or computer?).
There aren't many: only cases you'd need to check are $a = 3$ and $a=7$.

For $a=3$, we have $n=2$ and $m=4$.
For $a=7$ we have $n=m=4$.

This shows more than what was asked: not only is $a=7$ the only board size with $m=n=4$, it is the only board size with $m=n$.